# expo-auth-session not redirecting back to app when using facebook oauth

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-oauth

I am trying to build OAuth flow using expo-auth-session, the app supports login through both facebook and google, when using google oauth the Authentication flow redirects back to application. But while using facebook authentication, the authentication is successful but the browser is not redirecting back to app.

Right now I am using eas build in development mode to build the application

```
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-auth-session/providers/facebook';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

const [requestGoogle, responseGoogle, promptAsyncGoogle] = Google.useAuthRequest(
    {
      androidClientId: 'myandroidclientid'
      }
  );

  const [requestFacebook, responseFacebook, promptAsyncFacebook] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
    clientId: xxxxxx,
  });


<View style = {{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress = {()=> {promptAsyncGoogle({showInRecents: true})}}>
                <Image source = {require('../assets/backgroundImage/google.png')} style = {{height: 70, width:70}}/>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <View style = {{borderWidth:1, borderColor : 'black', height: 70}}/>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress = {()=>promptAsyncFacebook({showInRecents: true})}>
                <Image source = {require('../assets/backgroundImage/facebook2.png')} style = {{height: 70, width:70}}/>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
</View>
```

Any suggestion on why this is occurring will be really helpful. I have tried exploring approaches shared by other people who have faced the issue but nothing seems to work as of now.